# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input - why is that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is the code I have written using express and node.js

```
    const express = require("express");
    const https = require("https");
    const app = express();
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
        // Url to my api key
         const url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=...&number=1";
    
         https.get(url, function(response) {
    
              response.on("data", function (data) {
                   console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                   // const theRecipe = JSON.parse(data);
                   console.log(data);
              });
    
         });
    
         res.send("The server is up and running");
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, function () {
         console.log("Server started at port 3000");
    });
```

When I refresh my webpage on localhost, on console I get the following error:

> quote
> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
> at JSON.parse ()
> at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\ArunBohra\Desktop\FoodRecipes\app.js:12:33)
> quote

Can anyone find what is the problem with my code.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to parse a hexadecimal code to json format

Comment: This is simpler  - get the whole thing in one go `const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    const url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=...&number=1";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));`

Answer (score 4):

The `data` event fires when a **chunk** of data from the response has arrived. You are trying to parse the first chunk as if it were the complete JSON text.

You need to collect the pieces from each `data` event but wait until the `end` event fires before joining them together into the complete string of JSON that you can parse.

There is an [example of fetching and parsing JSON in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpgeturl-options-callback).

You might want to look at modules like [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) which take care of that (and the JSON parsing) for you while providing modern Promise based APIs.

If you have a new enough version of Node, you can use the [native Fetch API](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a package like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) you can get the whole thing in one go instead of what you have now which is chunking the data

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=...&number=1";
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what package are you talking about.
Also I want to what part of code should I replace it with.

Comment: I linked to the package and my code replaces the get in your code

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you can do it without another package.

```
https.get(url, function (response) {
    let result = "";
    response.on("data", function (data) {
        result += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        // now you have the combined result
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the result at line 2.

Comment: it's just a variable to hold all chunks, check the example of the doc here  https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/http/#httprequestoptions-callback